# Numbering inside the table (in second column) is not coming to the proper position

Tags: vertical-alignment

Numbering inside the table (in second column) is not coming to the proper position, going below the figure. If we use \begin{enumerate} it shows error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            abcd & xyz\\
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{C}  &(a)~\includegraphics[height=2.0cm]{square.png}\\
            &(b)~\includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{circle.png}\\
            \hline  
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[(a) & (b) are not at middle of figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUJYd.png)

Comment: @gernot I think that the OP wants an enumeration if possible, so probably no duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I got your question right, but in my understanding, you want to be able to use an `enumerate`-environment inside a `tabular`. In this case, you might do the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{pbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    abcd & xyz\\
    \hline
    C & \parbox{0.3\textwidth}{
        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item\pbox[c]{\textwidth}{\includegraphics[height=2.0cm]{example-image-a}}
            \item\pbox[c]{\textwidth}{\includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{example-image-b}}
        \end{enumerate}
    }\\
    \hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The `\pbox` is only used to center the enumerate-labels vertically. In this rather simple solution you have to adjust the width of the `\parbox` yourself.

[image: results]

If you don't want to use `enumerate` inside the table, still the `\usepackage{pbox}` and `\pbox[c]{\textwidth}{\includegraphics{...}}` works to vertically center the labels. Note that the `\textwidth` inside the `\pbox` is the maximum allowed width, but `\pbox` only uses the necessary space.

Answer (score 1):

Two things need to be fixed. First, the `c` column type does not support `enumerate`, you need `p`, `X`, or `m`. If you don't like using `X` with `tabularx`, then `m` from the array package will be the best choice. Second, to vertically center the images, the `valign=m` option from `adjustbox` package comes in handy.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|m{5cm}|}
            \hline
            abcd & xyz\\
            \hline
            C &
            \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item \includegraphics[height=2.0cm,valign=m]{example-image-a}
            \item \includegraphics[height=1.4cm,valign=m]{example-image-b}
            \end{enumerate} \\            
            \hline  
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]